# I want to import my email contacts from Mac OS X gmail account into Thunderbird. How?

Tags: thunderbird, gmail

I am running Ubuntu on a VM.  I want to import my email contacts from Mac OS X google mail account into Thunderbird on Linux.  How?

Answer (score 2):

Export your Google Mail contacts to a single file like it is explained [here](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=24911). Then upload it to a personal storage (that is encrypted) to which you have access via a web interface from inside the virtual machine. In the client, download the file and import the exported contacts via the address-book (you can find it in the extras or by pressing its shortcut: [`ctrl`]+[`shift`]+[`b`]). There go to Extras->Import and you will be able to select the file you have created.

Thunderbird should be able to open all the file types that Google can export.

It would be even easier, if you would be using the online accounts that were introduced in 11.10 (iirc) with Evolution. You can start it from the control panel, enter your Google contact information and directly sync your address book. That does not work with Thunderbird though.